# Python Selenium - Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to select an element in a drop down box from a work website.
I am a bit new to web scraping + selenium and need some pointing in the right direction.
Other similar questions I have found have a more obvious id path that could be used in comparison to my example, so I am slightly stuck.

[Screenshot of html and website layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE11k.png)

The options I would like to select seem to be altered by the aria-activedescendant value, e.g. aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--option-5"

I have tried the following code but I get the fault in the title when trying this.

```
select_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'Select-input')
select_object = Select(select_element)
select_object.select_by_visible_text('Author')
```

Comment: Select() method only works on <SELECT> tags.  You're tagetting a <DIV> there.  You can just use .click() method... i.e.: select_element.click()

Comment: @pcalkins is 100% correct. If you don't want to click on the element, please describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to select the 'Author' option in the dropdown, this is the element I am stuck with and select_element.click() will click the dropdown but won't select the 'Author' option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a chain of `Keys.TAB` commands or `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` to get your desired input. Use something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

el = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'Select-input').click()

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()
```